# Messenger Bot: Private Reply not working for newly created page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I have 2 pages in my facebook account and both pages are connected to the same bot. But, private reply working only for one page. It didn't working for newly created page. Showing the error:

"(#10903) This user cant reply to this activity".

Can anyone help me to understand why? Bot is replying to all other questions except private reply for newly created page.

Comment: Are you sure you are using different access_tokens for your two different pages?

Comment: Yes. I got the issue, one page didn't got all the permissions when subscribed the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the issue, one page didn't got all the permissions when subscribed the app. 'read_page_mailboxes' permission was missing from one page that caused the issue.

Note: For those who referring this or facing this issue, you can check if your access token included the required permissions granted by making a GET request to

```
/debug_token?input_token={input-token}
```

See more info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/debug_token)